# Azure Cloud Services: maintaining object references across different requests

Tags: c#, azure-cloud-services

I have a (classic) cloud service that needs to create an expensive object that I want to be reused in subsequent requests. It takes a long time to create so creating it each time slows down the requests unacceptably.

```
public class MyService : IHttpHandler
{
    public static ExpensiveObject MyObject;

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (MyObject == null) 
            MyObject = new ExpensiveObject();  // very time consuming operation

        // do stuff with MyObject
    }
}
```

(I realise the lack of consideration for multiple concurrent requests running, please disregard that) When I post two requests, one after the other, it creates a new `MyObject` each time. How can I ensure that it reuses the same object created for each request?

Setting `IsReusable` to return true in the `MyService` seemingly makes no difference.

Comment: Could you give more details - what *ExpensiveObject* do, why its instantiation takes a long time, which data is shared between subsequent request?

Comment: @vladimir I was hoping to keep this question a little more abstract. In my case it's a Tensorflow graph getting loaded and then re-used in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this easily (without dealing with arcane Azure crap) I just made a separate executable that hosts the `ExpensiveObject` in a [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) localhost server (started in a startup script).

In my case this has no significant drawbacks as I just need to request the object to consume a string and return another string. This might not be the right solution for everyone however.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re running inside IIS *you cant*. The application pool is at work. Additionally, multiple requests typically won’t cross paths in-process.

Your typical options include the following. It will only create one expensive service per thread:

1. IoC registering the service’s lifecycle per thread (or request scope).
2. a singleton (app pool already in use)

-Best of luck!

Comment: Is this what you mean by singleton? https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton - I can't immediately see how this could help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to move out the shared object from HttpHandler to separate hosted service, for example, Azure App Service, Azure WebJob (it isn't suited for all scenarios of using), etc.

*Azure App Service scenario*: web app communicates with App Service by HTTP (see [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)). Azure App Service has the configuration option [Always On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common) that keep the app loaded even when there's no traffic.

If you deal with a long-running operation (although you wrote that problem is long-initialization) then make sense to look at the standard REST-pattern resolving such problems - [Polling](http://restalk-patterns.org/long-running-operation-polling.html).

Maybe this link be useful for you: [Common causes of Cloud Service roles recycling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-common-issues-which-cause-roles-recycle).

Comment: Polling is definitely not relevant here, I want to share initialized objects between requests. I know it's technically possible to do this, as I could just start up a process on each VM that receives "sub-requests" that already has the necessary stuff loaded up, so I'm surprised Azure doesn't offer a canonical way of doing this